# Determine extra value in two python series or dataframes

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, series

Given two dataframes where i extract out some unique value into a groupby, i then want to compare two unique values and find the values that are different.

```
unit1 = ["U1", "U2", "U1", "U2", "U1", "U2"]
unit2 = ["U1", "U2", "U1", "U2", "U1", "U2, "U3"]
count1 = [2,4,6,8,10,12]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Unit': unit1,
                   'Count': count1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Unit': unit2,
                   'Count': count1})

units_in_1 = df.groupby(['Unit'])
unit1_list = units_in_1['Unit'].unique()

units_in_2 = df2.groupby(['Unit'])
unit2_list = units_in_2['Unit'].unique()
```

What i want in the end is U3 so that i can go back and find all instances of that in df2.

unit1_list is a series and i can't seem to get anything to work.

creating a list and doing an intersection as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025419/common-items-in-two-python-generators) fails with the famous numpy not hashable

If i try subtraction i get TypeError unsupported operand for str and str

Help please.

Comment: I used the solution from @chinmay as that taught me a bit more about python. I did not try the solution from edchum but it certainly looks like it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin()` with the negation (`~`) operator to achieve this.

```
>>> stuff_in_df2_but_not_in_df1 = df2[~df2.Unit.isin(df1.Unit)]['Unit'].unique()
['U3']
```

This somewhat arcane line of code tells Pandas to give you all items in `df2['Unit']` that are not present in `df1['Unit']`.

If you want this to work in both directions (i.e., you want a list of things that are in `df1` but not in `df2` *and* stuff that's in `df2` but not in `df1`, you could use `set.symmetric_difference()`.

If `df1['Unit']` contains `U1, U2, U4` and `df2['Unit']` contains `U1, U2, U3`, the following code would give you a `set()` containing `{'U3', 'U4'}`.

```
>>> set(df1.Unit.unique()).symmetric_difference(set(df2.Unit.unique()))
{'U3', 'U4'}
```

Comment: That does the trick. It's simple, well one line anyway, and i think i understand how it is working. I'll know i've learned when i have to something close but not exact and i can translate that snippet into something else. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm understanding your question.

Does it work if you select any value of df2['Unit] that isn't equal to df['Unit]?

```
df2[df.Unit != df2.Unit ]
```

output:
    [image]

Comment: No this doesn't work. My bad in making the example i made the lists the same size. The real data is of different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC then you can create a `set` of the unique values and then call `difference`:

```
In [161]:
combined = set(df['Unit'].unique().tolist()+df2['Unit'].unique().tolist())
combined

Out[161]:
{'U1', 'U2', 'U3'}

In [162]:    
combined.difference(df['Unit'].unique())

Out[162]:
{'U3'}
```